# How to get rid of random discontinuities in raw audio signal in C++ using Win32?

Tags: c++, winapi, audio

I want to continuously and seamlessly feed raw audio data into a cyclic buffer in small time intervals in C++ using Win32. The `header.lpData` buffer of `WAVEHDR` contains the raw audio data and by calling `waveInAddBuffer(wi, &header, sizeof(WAVEHDR));` this buffer is cyclically overwritten in small time intervals. The image below shows the problem:

While the buffer repeatedly is overwritten in small chunks (from left to right, current offset is displayed by magenta line and visible in the wave having a discontinuity at the magenta line), there are additional discontinuities in the wave at random places (yellow lightning). I've written the same thing in Java a few years ago and there it works flawlessly without discontinuities in the audio input.

Is there something I'm doing wrong or is this a bug in the Win32 audio library?

[image]

Here is the relevant part of my C++ code:

```c
#define VC_EXTRALEAN
#pragma comment(lib,"winmm.lib")
#include <Windows.h>

const int sample_rate = 4*4096; // must be supported by microphone
const int sample_size = 4096; // must be a power of 2

const int buffer_size = 2*sample_size;
char* buffer = new char[buffer_size];
float* wave = new float[sample_size];
int offset = 0;

void convert(float* const wave, const char* const buffer, int offset) {
    const float scale = 4.0f/65536.0f;
    for(int i=0; i<sample_size; i++) {
        const uint p = (offset-1+sample_size-i)%(buffer_size/2);
        wave[i] = scale*(float)((buffer[2*p+1]<<8)|(buffer[2*p]&0xFF));
    }
}

int main() {
    for(uint i=0; i<buffer_size; i++) buffer[i] = 0;
    for(uint i=0; i<sample_size; i++) wave[i] = 0.0f;

    WAVEFORMATEX wfx = {};
    wfx.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;    // PCM is standard
    wfx.nChannels = 1;                   // 1 channel (mono)
    wfx.nSamplesPerSec = sample_rate;    // sample_rate
    wfx.wBitsPerSample = 16;             // 16 bit samples
    wfx.nBlockAlign = wfx.wBitsPerSample*wfx.nChannels/8;
    wfx.nAvgBytesPerSec = wfx.nBlockAlign*wfx.nSamplesPerSec*wfx.nChannels;
    wfx.cbSize = 0;
    HWAVEIN wi;                          // open recording device
    WAVEHDR header = {};                 // initialize header empty
    header.dwFlags = 0;                  // clear the 'done' flag
    header.dwBytesRecorded = 0;          // tell it no bytes have been recorded
    header.lpData = buffer;              // give it a pointer to our buffer
    header.dwBufferLength = buffer_size; // tell it the size of that buffer in bytes
    waveInOpen(&wi, WAVE_MAPPER, &wfx, NULL, NULL, CALLBACK_NULL|WAVE_FORMAT_DIRECT);
    waveInStart(wi); // start recording
    waveInPrepareHeader(wi, &header, sizeof(WAVEHDR)); // prepare header

    while(true) {
        waveInAddBuffer(wi, &header, sizeof(WAVEHDR)); // read in new audio data into buffer
        offset = header.dwBytesRecorded; // get offset of to which point the buffer is overwritten
    
        convert(wave, buffer, offset);
        // plot wave and offset

        sleep(1.0/120.0); // time in seconds
    }
    waveInUnprepareHeader(wi, &header, sizeof(WAVEHDR));
    waveInStop(wi); // once the user hits escape, stop recording, and clean up
    waveInClose(wi);
}
```

EDIT: I tried the solution from @Adrian McCarthy and it does not work as pointed out in the comment. The modified code is:

```c
#define VC_EXTRALEAN
#pragma comment(lib,"winmm.lib")
#include <Windows.h>

const int sample_rate = 4*4096; // must be supported by microphone
const int sample_size = 4096; // must be a power of 2

const uint buffer_size = 2*sample_size/8; // make buffers 1/8 the size of the total wave buffer
char* buffer1 = new char[buffer_size];
char* buffer2 = new char[buffer_size];
float* wave = new float[sample_size];
int offset = 0;

void convert(float* const wave, const char* const buffer, int offset) {
    const float scale = 4.0f/65536.0f;
    for(int i=sample_size-1; i>=offset/2; i--) {
        wave[i] = wave[i-offset/2];
    }
    for(int i=0; i<offset/2; i++) {
        const uint p = offset/2-1-i;
        wave[i] = scale*(float)((buffer[2*p+1]<<8)|(buffer[2*p]&0xFF));
    }
}

int main() {
    for(uint i=0; i<buffer_size; i++) buffer1[i] = 0;
    for(uint i=0; i<buffer_size; i++) buffer2[i] = 0;
    for(uint i=0; i<sample_size; i++) wave[i] = 0.0f;

    WAVEFORMATEX wfx = {};
    wfx.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;    // PCM is standard
    wfx.nChannels = 1;                   // 1 channel (mono)
    wfx.nSamplesPerSec = sample_rate;    // sample_rate
    wfx.wBitsPerSample = 16;             // 16 bit samples
    wfx.nBlockAlign = wfx.wBitsPerSample*wfx.nChannels/8;
    wfx.nAvgBytesPerSec = wfx.nBlockAlign*wfx.nSamplesPerSec*wfx.nChannels;
    wfx.cbSize = 0;
    HWAVEIN wi;                             // open recording device
    WAVEHDR* pCurrent = new WAVEHDR();      // initialize header empty
    pCurrent->dwFlags = 0;                  // clear the 'done' flag
    pCurrent->dwBytesRecorded = 0;          // tell it no bytes have been recorded
    pCurrent->lpData = buffer1;             // give it a pointer to our buffer
    pCurrent->dwBufferLength = buffer_size; // tell it the size of that buffer in bytes
    WAVEHDR* pNext = new WAVEHDR();         // initialize header empty
    pNext->dwFlags = 0;                     // clear the 'done' flag
    pNext->dwBytesRecorded = 0;             // tell it no bytes have been recorded
    pNext->lpData = buffer2;                // give it a pointer to our buffer
    pNext->dwBufferLength = buffer_size;    // tell it the size of that buffer in bytes
    waveInOpen(&wi, WAVE_MAPPER, &wfx, NULL, NULL, CALLBACK_NULL|WAVE_FORMAT_DIRECT);
    waveInStart(wi); // start recording
    waveInPrepareHeader(wi, pCurrent, sizeof(WAVEHDR)); // prepare header
    waveInPrepareHeader(wi, pNext   , sizeof(WAVEHDR)); // prepare header

    while(true) {
        do {
            waveInAddBuffer(wi, pCurrent, sizeof(WAVEHDR));
            sleep(0.001);
        } while((pCurrent->dwFlags&WHDR_DONE)==0);
        pCurrent->dwFlags &= ~WHDR_DONE;
        swap(pCurrent, pNext);

        offset = pCurrent->dwBytesRecorded; // get offset of to which point the buffer is overwritten
    
        convert(wave, buffer1, offset);
        // plot wave and offset

        sleep(1.0/120.0); // time in seconds
    }
    waveInUnprepareHeader(wi, pCurrent, sizeof(WAVEHDR));
    waveInUnprepareHeader(wi, pNext   , sizeof(WAVEHDR));
    waveInStop(wi); // once the user hits escape, stop recording, and clean up
    waveInClose(wi);
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Are you overwriting `buffer` after having it passed on to the system? If so, there's no reason to have any expectations. This is not how the system is designed to work.

Comment: No, outside of the code shown above, `buffer` is used read-only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problems:

- Your thread is racing with a system thread that's filling the buffer and updating the fields in the header.  When you read the `dwBytesRecorded` field, you can get a value less than the number of bytes actually in the buffer.  The thread filling the buffer will occasionally update `dwBytesRecorded`, but that number will be out-of-date a split second later, as the recording continues.  And that's optimistically assuming that reading a DWORD while another thread may be writing to it is safe.
- When you add the buffer again, the audio system believes this is a new buffer to switch to as soon as the current one is full.  You're passing it the same buffer, hoping it will just start filling it from the beginning.
  But it might also be twiddling the Reserved fields in the header and create an inconsistent state.
- I'm not sure which `sleep` function you're using, but most of them can't/don't wait for a precise amount of time.  The Win32 `Sleep` will wait *at least* the number of milliseconds specified and then mark the thread as ready-to-run, but it doesn't actually run until the scheduler gets around to it.  In practice, this might not be a problem, since your buffer is 500 milliseconds, which is an order of magnitude larger than the uncertainty from the sleep.

The typical way to implement this is to ping-pong between two (or more) buffers.  You add two very short buffers, and wait for the first one to get the `WHDR_DONE` flag set in its header [see Note].  You then process the entire first buffer at once while the system continues to record into the second buffer.  Once you're done processing a buffer, you re-add it, and then wait for the other buffer to become ready.

```
// Given two buffers `ping` and `pong` with corresponding WAVEHDRs
// `ping_header` and `pong_header`...
WAVEHDR *pCurrent = ping_header;
WAVEHDR *pNext = pong_header;
waveInAddBuffer(wi, pCurrent, sizeof(WAVEHDR));
waveInAddBuffer(wi, pNext, sizeof(WAVEHDR));

for (;;) {
  // wait for the current buffer to fill
  while ((pCurrent->dwFlags & WHDR_DONE) == 0) {}  // SEE NOTE

  // As recording continues with *pNext, process and draw
  // the data from pCurrent->lpData.

  // Now that we're done processing pCurrent, we can re-add it so
  // the system has a place to record when pNext is full.
  waveInAddBuffer(wi, pCurrent, sizeof(WAVEHDR));
  // What was next becomes current, and the new next is the old current.
  swap(pCurrent, pNext);
}
```

Note that your two buffers can be pretty short.  I'd recommend 16-20 ms: larger than the default 15.6 ms timer on Windows, but still in the ballpark of how much data you were trying to process in each loop iteration.

The busy wait loop here isn't great--it can drive a core to 100% without doing useful work.  But if the processing time is close to the time it takes to record the next buffer, then it won't spin too much.  (And technically, you still have the same data-race issue of reading a variable while another thread may be updating it, but we're just watching for the bit to go high, so it's probably OK in practice.)

The wave audio APIs weren't designed for extreme high-speed processing.  They were intended for Windows programs.  Instead of busy waiting for the flag, you were expected to process the [MM_WIM_DATA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/multimedia/mm-wim-data) message in a window's window procedure, which would avoid the busy waiting and the data races, but add a bit of message passing overhead as each buffer completes.

2020-07-19

**Note**:  @ProjectPhysX pointed out that the busy wait loop for `WHDR_DONE` in my code outline doesn't work.  The compiler is free to assume that the value never changes and likely optimizes the code to test the flag once and then spin forever.  That's allowed because the data race between our waiting thread and the thread that sets the flag means the code has "undefined behavior".  If we controlled both threads, we could use any sort of synchronization scheme to eliminate the data race, and this would work.  But we don't have access to the thread(s) running in the audio system.

The wave audio APIs were designed to notify the client when a buffer is done by sending it a window message.  That works fine for continuous recording, but it means taking an event-driven approach and the overhead of message passing *may* limit how fast the program can process the samples.  Either of XAudio2 or  Windows Core Audio would be more appropriate for high-speed audio work.  The idea of using a pair (or chain) of small buffers is pretty universal, and is analogous to graphics programs using a back buffer or swap chain.

Comment: Doesn't work. There is no racing between threads to begin with. In my main thread, `buffer` is alternatingly filled (`waveInAddBuffer` is blocking) and then used read-only (during which there is no 2nd thread writing to it). The background thread initiated by `waveInStart` doesn't write into `buffer` on its own.
Waiting until the buffer is full ensures that it is filled entirely and without discontinuities in it. But I want a larger cyclic buffer to be continuously fed by small chunks.
With 2 small ping-pong headers, the wave has discontinuities where the buffers are stitched together.

Comment: @pro We cannot see your code. If you need help, post a [mcve].

Comment: @IInspectable I've now added the implementation of Adrian McCarthy's answer.

Comment: @ProjectPhysX:  waveInAddBuffer does not block.  Once the buffer is added to the queue, it returns.  Meanwhile, a separate thread is writing the data to the queued buffers as well as updating the WAVEHDRs themselves.  Trying to read the data or the WAVEHDR before you've been "notified" that it's ready is technically a data race.

Comment: The updated code does not match what I outlined.  Note that I started by adding BOTH buffers before the loop.  You always need to ensure that there is at least one more buffer available or the recording process will drop samples.  (The docs say, "If there are no buffers in the queue, the data is thrown away without notifying the application, and input continues.")  The new code is adding the first buffer over and over until it's full.  Once it's full, the code calls convert and does another sleep.  During that whole time, the recording thread has nowhere to put the incoming samples.

Comment: Using multiple buffers doesn't mean the data can't be contiguous.  You can allocate one big chunk of memory, set up one WAVEHDR to point to the first half and the other to point to the second half.  If you want even finer resolution, you can use _n_ WAVEHDRs to point at each of _n_ sections.  If you add them to the queue in order, your big buffer will fill in order.

Comment: @Adrian McCarthy with your solution implemented 1:1, the program never gets past the line `while((pCurrent->dwFlags&WHDR_DONE)==0) {}`. `WHDR_DONE` somehow is never set. When adding a `this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1));` in the while loop, `WHDR_DONE` is set, but the two buffers again have gaps in between.

Comment: @ProjectPhysX:  Technically the data race triggers undefined behavior.  As an optimization, the compiler may not be generating code to reload the flag since, as far as it knows, it can't change, so it's likely just spinning.  Inserting the sleep might perturb the optimizer enough to reload the register.  As I said before, this (very old) API was never designed to be used this way.  It was designed to send a windows message when a buffer is ready to be processed.  You may need to use Windows Core Audio instead.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the suggestions of Ben Voigt, I revisited and updated my code:

```c
const uint N = 16;
char** buffers = new char*[N];

int main() {
    for(uint n=0; n<N; n++) {
        buffers[n] = new char[buffer_size];
        for(uint i=0; i<buffer_size; i++) {
            buffers[n][i] = 0;
        }
    }
    Clock clock;

    WAVEFORMATEX wfx = {};
    wfx.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;    // PCM is standard
    wfx.nChannels = 1;                   // 1 channel (mono)
    wfx.nSamplesPerSec = sample_rate;    // sample_rate
    wfx.wBitsPerSample = 16;             // 16 bit samples
    wfx.nBlockAlign = wfx.wBitsPerSample*wfx.nChannels/8;
    wfx.nAvgBytesPerSec = wfx.nBlockAlign*wfx.nSamplesPerSec*wfx.nChannels;
    wfx.cbSize = 0;

    HWAVEIN wi;                          // open recording device
    volatile WAVEHDR** headers = new volatile WAVEHDR*[N]; // initialize header empty
    waveInOpen(&wi, WAVE_MAPPER, &wfx, NULL, NULL, CALLBACK_NULL|WAVE_FORMAT_DIRECT);
    waveInStart(wi); // start recording
    for(uint n=0; n<N; n++) {
        headers[n] = new WAVEHDR{};
        headers[n]->dwFlags = 0;                  // clear the 'done' flag
        headers[n]->dwBytesRecorded = 0;          // tell it no bytes have been recorded
        headers[n]->lpData = buffers[n];          // give it a pointer to our buffer
        headers[n]->dwBufferLength = buffer_size; // tell it the size of that buffer in bytes
        waveInPrepareHeader(wi, (WAVEHDR*)headers[n], sizeof(WAVEHDR)); // prepare header
        waveInAddBuffer(wi, (WAVEHDR*)headers[n], sizeof(WAVEHDR));
    }

    uint n = 0;
    while(running) {
        while((headers[n]->dwFlags&WHDR_DONE)==0);
        const int offset = headers[n]->dwBytesRecorded/2;

        if(offset>0) {
            // add recorded buffer[n] to larger circular buffer
        }

        headers[n]->dwBytesRecorded = 0;
        headers[n]->dwFlags &= ~WHDR_DONE;
        waveInAddBuffer(wi, (WAVEHDR*)headers[n], sizeof(WAVEHDR));
        n = (n+1)%N;

        sleep(1.0/120.0-clock.stop());
        clock.start();
    }
    for(uint n=0; n<N; n++) {
        waveInUnprepareHeader(wi, (WAVEHDR*)headers[n], sizeof(WAVEHDR));
    }
    waveInStop(wi); // once the user hits escape, stop recording, and clean up
    waveInClose(wi);
}
```

Using `N=16` or even more buffers, the discontinuities get less frequent, but are still present in about 1-2 of every 8 stitching places.

Comment: You have continual clock slippage.  The `sleep(1.0/120.0-clock.stop());` is not necessary at all, because the `while((headers[n]->dwFlags&WHDR_DONE)==0);` will spin for the correct amount of time.  But the spin is inefficient, so having some amount of sleep is a good idea, but you should be careful not to let error accumulate, and you should always underestimate the sleep time, because it's better to spin than to lose samples.

Comment: A better way to do an efficient sleep would be using the `CALLBACK_EVENT` flag with `waveOpen`, the handle to an auto-reset event, and `WaitForSingleObject` for your sleep.  But you still need to handle the case where two buffers get filled using one wait.  Because you haven't done that, no matter how many buffers you start with, you eventually lose them all.  And more buffers is merely delaying the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Your ping-pong approach (after the edit) has several pretty severe mistakes:

1. You shouldn't be calling `waveInAddBuffer` inside the loop waiting for `WHDR_DONE`. Call it once. Now the OS owns the buffer. You can't do *anything* with it until the "done" flag is set, and you certainly can't pass it to `waveInAddBuffer` a second and third time.
2. You are processing pCurrent after calling swap, which means you are processing the wrong buffer.
3. During your processing the OS doesn't have any buffer to use, which is why you lose data.

Correct logic:

- Give the OS both buffers.
- Loop:

  - Wait for "current" buffer to be flagged done.
  - Process "current".
  - Reset the flags and give "current" to the OS again.
  - Swap your concept of "current" and "next".

Funny, Adrian's code matches this correct order, and yours does everything out of order.  Doesn't seem like you tried his approach at all.

Because you do need the sleep inside the flag-testing code, and because the scheduler quantum is about as long as your buffer length, it's possible that two buffers will become done during a single sleep.  This means that

a. You need at least three buffers

b. You need a while loop not do-while, so you can sometimes process two buffers before entering sleep again.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. The thing is, Adrian's code 1:1 does not work at all, as I have discussed with him in the comments. The `WHDR_DONE` flag is never set and the program hangs at the line `while ((pCurrent->dwFlags & WHDR_DONE) == 0) {}`. The API does not function properly.

Comment: @ProjectPhysX: You're completely misdirecting the blame.  The API is setting the flag just fine, but Adrian's code wasn't actually polling it.  Putting a sleep in forces the compiler to access the original memory location again instead of the register it copied the value into.

Comment: Thank you for this remark! I tried Adrian's solution once again (exactly in the suggested order), but this time making `pCurrent`/`pNext` type `volatile WAVEHDR*`. This forces polling from memory and solves the `WHDR_DONE` polling issue. The `while` loop now does not block forever. However: At the places where  `pCurrent`/`pNext` are stiched together, there are still discontinuities. Any ideas?

Comment: I would certainly try with a chain of 3 or 4 buffers (you can make an array of `WAVE_HDR`, no need to dynamically allocate with `new`.  And then instead of `swap`, you'll keep track of a "current" index into the array, incrementing it with wrap-around.)

Comment: Thank you once again. I've updated my code and put it in a new answer to this question. With a chain of several buffers, discontinuities get less frequent, but I still can't get rid of them all. Let me know if I'm still doing something wrong in my code.

Comment: @ProjectPhysX: You overlooked my final sentence in your latest implementation.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry but I don't get that last point. If I remove all sleep calls (process any new buffer immediately), then I still get discontinuies. Also could you provide the code for handling `CALLBACK_EVENT`? Im not familiar with Windows events and the Microsoft Developer website is not helpful at all.