# How to record continuous raw audio data into a circular buffer with C++ on Windows 10?

Tags: c++, windows, audio

Since [Windows Multimedia turned out to be utterly incapable of recording continuous audio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62968248/9178992), I got the hint to use Windows Core Audio. There is sort of a manual [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/coreaudio/loopback-recording?redirectedfrom=MSDN), but I can't figure out how to write the loads of overhead code to get the recording working. Can anyone provide a complete, minimal implementation of continuous audio recording to a circular buffer?

So far I am stuck at the code below not getting past the line `pEnumerator->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(eRender, eConsole, &pDevice);` because `pEnumerator` remains `nullptr`.

```c
#define VC_EXTRALEAN
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Audioclient.h>
#include <Mmdeviceapi.h>

#define REFTIMES_PER_SEC  10000000
#define REFTIMES_PER_MILLISEC  10000

int main() {
    REFERENCE_TIME hnsRequestedDuration = REFTIMES_PER_SEC;
    UINT32 bufferFrameCount;
    UINT32 numFramesAvailable;

    IMMDeviceEnumerator* pEnumerator = NULL;
    IMMDevice* pDevice = NULL;
    IAudioClient* pAudioClient = NULL;
    IAudioCaptureClient* pCaptureClient = NULL;
    WAVEFORMATEX* pwfx = NULL;
    UINT32 packetLength = 0;
    BYTE* pData;
    DWORD flags;

    CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator), NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator), (void**)&pEnumerator);
    pEnumerator->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(eRender, eConsole, &pDevice);
    pDevice->Activate(__uuidof(IAudioClient), CLSCTX_ALL, NULL, (void**)&pAudioClient);
    pAudioClient->GetMixFormat(&pwfx);
    pAudioClient->Initialize(AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE_SHARED, AUDCLNT_STREAMFLAGS_LOOPBACK, hnsRequestedDuration, 0, pwfx, NULL);
    pAudioClient->GetBufferSize(&bufferFrameCount); // Get the size of the allocated buffer.
    pAudioClient->GetService(__uuidof(IAudioCaptureClient), (void**)&pCaptureClient);

    // Calculate the actual duration of the allocated buffer.
    REFERENCE_TIME hnsActualDuration = (double)REFTIMES_PER_SEC* bufferFrameCount / pwfx->nSamplesPerSec;

    pAudioClient->Start();  // Start recording.

    // Each loop fills about half of the shared buffer.
    while(true) {
        // Sleep for half the buffer duration.
        Sleep(hnsActualDuration/REFTIMES_PER_MILLISEC/2);
        pCaptureClient->GetNextPacketSize(&packetLength);
        while(packetLength != 0) {
            // Get the available data in the shared buffer.
            pCaptureClient->GetBuffer(&pData, &numFramesAvailable, &flags, NULL, NULL);
            if(flags&AUDCLNT_BUFFERFLAGS_SILENT) {
                pData = NULL;  // Tell CopyData to write silence.
            }

            // Copy the available capture data to the audio sink.
            //hr = pMySink->CopyData(pData, numFramesAvailable, &bDone);

            pCaptureClient->ReleaseBuffer(numFramesAvailable);
            pCaptureClient->GetNextPacketSize(&packetLength);
        }
    }
    pAudioClient->Stop();
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT (24.07.2021):

Here is an update of my code for troubleshooting:

```c
#define VC_EXTRALEAN
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Audioclient.h>
#include <Mmdeviceapi.h>

#include <chrono>
class Clock {
private:
    typedef chrono::high_resolution_clock clock;
    chrono::time_point<clock> t;
public:
    Clock() { start(); }
    void start() { t = clock::now(); }
    double stop() const { return chrono::duration_cast<chrono::duration<double>>(clock::now()-t).count(); }
};

const uint base        =   4096;
const uint sample_rate =  48000; // must be supported by microphone
const uint sample_size = 1*base; // must be a power of 2
const uint bandwidth   =   5000; // must be <= sample_rate/2

float* wave = new float[sample_size]; // circular buffer

void fill(float* const wave, const float* const buffer, int offset) {
    for(int i=sample_size; i>=offset; i--) {
        wave[i] = wave[i-offset];
    }
    for(int i=0; i<offset; i++) {
        const uint p = offset-1-i;
        wave[i] = 0.5f*(buffer[2*p]+buffer[2*p+1]); // left and right channels
    }
}

int main() {
    for(uint i=0; i<sample_size; i++) wave[i] = 0.0f;
    
    Clock clock;

    #define REFTIMES_PER_SEC  10000000
    #define REFTIMES_PER_MILLISEC  10000

    REFERENCE_TIME hnsRequestedDuration = REFTIMES_PER_SEC;
    UINT32 bufferFrameCount;
    UINT32 numFramesAvailable;

    IMMDeviceEnumerator* pEnumerator = NULL;
    IMMDevice* pDevice = NULL;
    IAudioClient* pAudioClient = NULL;
    IAudioCaptureClient* pCaptureClient = NULL;
    WAVEFORMATEX* pwfx = NULL;
    UINT32 packetLength = 0;
    BYTE* pData;
    DWORD flags;

    CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator), NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator), (void**)&pEnumerator);
    pEnumerator->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(eRender, eConsole, &pDevice);
    pDevice->Activate(__uuidof(IAudioClient), CLSCTX_ALL, NULL, (void**)&pAudioClient);
    pAudioClient->GetMixFormat(&pwfx);
    
    println(pwfx->wFormatTag);// 65534
    println(WAVE_FORMAT_PCM);// 1
    println(pwfx->nChannels);// 2
    println((uint)pwfx->nSamplesPerSec);// 48000
    println(pwfx->wBitsPerSample);// 32
    println(pwfx->nBlockAlign);// 8
    println(pwfx->wBitsPerSample*pwfx->nChannels/8);// 8
    println((uint)pwfx->nAvgBytesPerSec);// 384000
    println((uint)(pwfx->nBlockAlign*pwfx->nSamplesPerSec*pwfx->nChannels));// 768000
    println(pwfx->cbSize);// 22

    pAudioClient->Initialize(AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE_SHARED, AUDCLNT_STREAMFLAGS_LOOPBACK, hnsRequestedDuration, 0, pwfx, NULL);
    pAudioClient->GetBufferSize(&bufferFrameCount); // Get the size of the allocated buffer.
    pAudioClient->GetService(__uuidof(IAudioCaptureClient), (void**)&pCaptureClient);

    // Calculate the actual duration of the allocated buffer.
    //REFERENCE_TIME hnsActualDuration = (double)REFTIMES_PER_SEC* bufferFrameCount / pwfx->nSamplesPerSec;

    pAudioClient->Start();  // Start recording.
    
    while(running) {

        pCaptureClient->GetNextPacketSize(&packetLength); // packetLength and numFramesAvailable are either 0 or 480
        pCaptureClient->GetBuffer(&pData, &numFramesAvailable, &flags, NULL, NULL);

        const int offset = (uint)numFramesAvailable;
        if(offset>0) {
            fill(wave, (float*)pData, offset); // here I add pData to the circular buffer "wave"
        }

        while(packetLength != 0) {
            pCaptureClient->GetBuffer(&pData, &numFramesAvailable, &flags, NULL, NULL); // Get the available data in the shared buffer.
            if(flags&AUDCLNT_BUFFERFLAGS_SILENT) {
                pData = NULL;  // Tell CopyData to write silence.
            }
            pCaptureClient->ReleaseBuffer(numFramesAvailable);
            pCaptureClient->GetNextPacketSize(&packetLength);
        }

        sleep(1.0/120.0-clock.stop());
        clock.start();
    }
    pAudioClient->Stop();
}
```

Comment: Your other question was still calling Windows Multimedia horribly wrong, that's why you didn't get continuous audio.

Answer (score 2):

You're not calling [`CoInitializeEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-coinitializeex), so all COM calls will fail.

You should also be testing all calls to see if they return an error.

---

To address the questions posed in the comments:

I believe that if you want to operate the endpoint in shared mode then you have to use the parameters returned by `GetFixFormat`.  This means that:

- you are limited to the one sample rate (unless you write code to perform a conversion, which is a non-trivial task)
- if you want the samples as floats, you will have to convert them yourself

To write code that runs on all machines, you must cater for whatever the mix format throws at you.  This might be:

- 16 bit integers
- 24 bit integers (nBlockAlign = 3)
- 24 bit integers in 32 bit containers (nBlockAlign = 4)
- 32 bit integers
- 32 bit floating point (rare)
- 64 bit floating point (unheard of, in my experience)

The samples will be in the native byte order of the machine your code is running on, and are interleaved.

So, case out on the various parameters in `pwfx` and write the relevant code for each sample format you want to support.

Assuming you want your `float`s to be normalised to `-1 .. +1`, and 2-channel input data, you might do this for 16 bit integers, for example:

```
const int16_t *inbuf = (const int16_t *) pData;
float *outbuf = ...;

for (int i = 0; i < numFramesAvailable * 2; ++i)
{
    int16_t sample = *inbuf++;
    *outbuf++ = (float) (sample * (1.0 / 32767));
}
```

Note that I avoid a (slow) floating point division by multiplying by the reciprocal (the compiler will pre-calculate `1.0 / 32767`).

I'll leave the rest to you.

Comment: Thank you. Now it runs without errors at least. But I can't change the attributes of `pwfx` (`pCaptureClient` remains `nullptr` if I change any of the attributes), so I am stuck with whatever audio format `pAudioClient->GetMixFormat(&pwfx);` returns. Also I can't figure out how the byte order in `pData` is. Here is what I want: A float array that holds the amplitude for each point in time for 1s (so 48k entries). I want to continuously (~60 times a second) and without discontinuities feed this array with new audio data (FIFO). Can you please provide a minimum working example?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you once again. I found out that for whatever reason the `pData` buffer already is formatted as `float`s, so casting would mess things up. But more importantly, similar to the other question I have linked in my question above, audio frames are discontinuous. Is there a workaround with chaining multiple recording buffers?

Comment: How are you processing the audio after it is returned in `pData`?  Maybe there's a bug in that code.  You shouldn't need to do anything special to avoid getting discontinuities in the audio.

Comment: I've added my updated code to the question.

Comment: I would debug `fill`.  It seems more complicated than it needs to be and I think there is at least one out-by-one error.  Also, what does `Clock` do?  Are you sure you're sleeping for the right amount of time.  Sleeping for too long will cause problems.

Comment: I've added the `Clock` definition. `clock.stop()` returns the elapsed time since `clock.start()` in seconds. Removing the clock or making the sleep interval shorter has no effect. Removing `sleep` causes freeze after some time. `fill` has no out-by one error: in `wave`, the interval [offset, sample_size[ is shifted back by offset, and the new part is added in [0, offset[. For `buffer` I access elements [0, 2*offset[ in reverse order. Not reversing the order is wrong. I have double-checked that `2*p` is left and `2*p+1` is right audio channel. Discontinuities are approx. at every 2nd stitch.

Comment: OK, well, the obvious thing to do is to try playing the audio before it is put in the circular buffer.  If it plays correctly then you know where the problem is.  Also, are you sure that buffer isn't  overflowing?  That would cause a glitch.

Comment: Visually inspecting the audio signal (for a sine wave) shows: Each audio frame of 480 samples is continuous. The boundaries where two neighboring frames connect are discontinuous as if a frame in between was missing. I have double-checked for buffer overflows, there is none. The flags and return value from `pCaptureClient->GetBuffer` both are 0.

Comment: I had some further thoughts.  If your buffer size is 480 samples and your sample rate is 48000 Hz, then each buffer-full is 10ms long (so you should be sleeping for 5ms).  But this is less than the granularity of `Sleep`, so it will often sleep for longer, which might lead to you missing some incoming data.  So try increasing your buffer size (as passed to `pAudioClient->Initialize`) to see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Increasing `hnsRequestedDuration` in `pAudioClient->Initialize` has no effect at all. Frame size is always 480.

Comment: I took a closer look at your second code sample and it's all wrong.  Using the first sample as a reference, do things the same way and get rid of the nested `while` loop.  Also, call `Sleep` in the same way as in the first sample - I still don't trust what you're doing there.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. My first and revised sample only differ in `CoInitializeEx`, the buffer stitching with `fill` and the `sleep`. Sleep has no effect on continuity whatsoever and `fill` works correctly. The rest follows exactly the code sample from MS Developer, https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/coreaudio/capturing-a-stream First `while` is the main loop and 2nd `while` is required as shown on the MS website. I would be very greatful if you could just show me how to do it properly with a 20 line code paragraph. With only one tiny hint per comment this is getting nowhere.

Comment: No, the second code sample is very different from the first.  The inner `while` loop reads audio buffers without calling `fill`.  **You don't need two loops.** 
 And I'm not going to write your code for you, sorry.

Comment: Removing the inner `while loop and just calling `pCaptureClient->ReleaseBuffer` instead still dows not resolve discontinuities. Decreasing/removing `sleep` does not help either. It really would be much more helpful if you could actually show me how to do it properly.

Comment: It's really very simple.  Go back to your first sample code (which, since it is Microsoft's example code, we can assume works) and then call `fill` every time you get a buffer-full of data.  That's all.

Comment: The Microsoft sample does *not* work. I have tried countless times, every possible way. If it would have worked, I would not have had to write this question. Im getting more and more the feeling that Windows Core Audio is dysfunctional garbage, just like WASAPI that I tried in my other question. I've written the very same thing in Java years ago and there it worked first try without any trouble. Thank you again for your help and patience, but I think I will abandon Windows Core Audio once and for all now.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this audio library instead. Its way easier to get up and running than trying to interface with the platform specific SDKs:

[http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtaudio/recording.html](http://www.music.mcgill.ca/%7Egary/rtaudio/recording.html)

Also, while removing the sleep might not help in your example you should never call sleep, lock a mutex, or allocate memory during audio processing. The delay introduced by those is completely arbitrary compared to the short buffer times, so will always create problems for you.

Comment: ( Or see this example for doing input and output at the same time: http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtaudio/duplex.html )

Comment: Microsoft advocate calling `Sleep`.